# Groovy named parameter causing ClassCastException

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have a Groovy script which is run in Jenkins. For context, I am using the [SAML Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/saml-plugin), and specifically using the [SamlSecurityRealm](https://github.com/jenkinsci/saml-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/saml/SamlSecurityRealm.java#L154) constructor. This works fine.

However, to improve readability, I have attempted to used named parameters. The parameter `binding`, which is of type String, is causing the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to groovy.lang.Binding
```

My usage is like this:

```
binding = 'String value'
```

This syntax is working for all of the other parameters, and if I remove just this one named parameter, the script runs.

I am familiar with Java and Scala, but not so much with Groovy. `binding` does not seem to be a keyword, but I am assuming I need to escape it somehow? Wrapping it in single or double quotes, or backticks is also not working.

Comment: can you show the full code please? How you create the instance of SamlSecurityRealm and provide parameters.

Answer (score 1):

if you are inside groovy Script then `binding = XYZ` tries to call `Script.setBinding(XYZ)`

https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/Script.html

unless you declare a variable binding like this:

```
def binding = XYZ
```

Comment: Is there a way to escape the word `binding` so that it can be used for the named parameter?

Comment: `def binding` should work. Or show what is your case